# Error handling with Flux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I want to create a report where I save all failed uploads(only id) to a list. My example does only save the last item.  Did I miss anything? All successfull uploads should be filtered out.

Service:

```
Flux<Entity> fluxMerge = Flux.merge(fluxA, fluxB);

Mono<List<Long>> errorIds = fluxMerge.
            .onErrorResume(MyException.class, err -> Mono.just(err.getEntity()))
            .map(Entity::getId)
            .collectList();
```

RestService:

```
return Mono.create(monoSink -> 
                exchange.addCallback(result -> monoSink.success(result.getBody()),
                err -> monoSink.error(new MyException(entity))));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Reactivex documentaion http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html
says that error from any of merged fluxes will terminate the merged one. That is why `onErrorResume` handles only first error.

I can suggest 2 approaches

- add 'onErrorResume' handler to each of fluxes before merging them

  ```
  Flux<Entity> fluxMerge = Flux.merge(
      fluxA.onErrorResume(MyException.class, err -> Mono.just(err.getEntity())),
      fluxB.onErrorResume(MyException.class, err -> Mono.just(err.getEntity())));
  Mono<List<Long>> errorIds = fluxMerge.map(Entity::getId).collectList();
  ```
- model upload error as a message in the flux, use flux errors only for critical issues that just produce 503 on rest service

  ```
  return Mono.create(monoSink -> exchange.addCallback(
          result -> monoSink.success(new Success(result.getBody())),
          err -> monoSink.success(new UploadError(entity))));

  Flux<Result> fluxMerge = Flux.merge(fluxA, fluxB);
  Mono<List<Long>> errorIds = fluxMerge.filter(Result::isError).map(Result::entity).map(Entity::getId).collectList()

  interface Result{ 
      Boolean isError(); 
      Entity entity();             
  }
  class Success implements Result { ... }
  class UploadError implements Result { ... }
  ```

Comment: if use a onErrorResume for every flux, how can I combine the result?  I mean collect all error in one list?